# FFTW wisdom tool fails with large input matrix size

Tags: fftw

I'm trying to optimize fftw plans for a 65536x65536 matrix. 
When I run fftw-wisdom tool:

`fftwf-wisdom -n -m -T 12 -o wisdomfile.fftw rob65536x65536`

it fails with:

`bench: util.c:217: assertion failed: p`

I believe this is caused by the large matrix size.

What is the maximum supported input size? 
Is there any work around?

Comment: Are you running this on a 32 bit or a 64 bit OS ?

Comment: I'm running on 64 bit machine. I'm debugging fftw-wistom now, and I'm finding operations like this: int var = 65536x65536; 
There is integer overflow. FFTW should use size_t and not int to store the array size...

Comment: Yes, I just tried 65536x65536 on a 64 bit OS here and it fails. 32768x32768 seems to work OK, as does 65536x4 or 4x65536.

Comment: Is there any way to force 8-byte integers?
I'm trying to replace "int" by "size_t"...

Comment: All I can suggest is to try contacting the authors - their email addresses are given in the FFTW docs I believe.

Comment: Apparently, it is working now with my changes. Simply replaced a few int variables by size_t in some source files of fftw.

Comment: Cool - it might be worth sending those fixes to the authors so that they can be incorporated into a future release.